# Concatenating Lots of Interfaces Together in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have several interfaces like this

```
interface Foo { ... } 
interface Bar { ... }
interface Baz { ... }
...
```

and I want to 'or' them all together into one type like this

`type FBB = Foo | Bar | Baz | ...`

I have a lot of interfaces, so is there anyway I can do this programatically without having to hand write each and everyone into the `FBB` type?

Comment: Can you change the way the `interfaces`s are declared? Do they have to be `interface`s or would `type` aliases work?

Comment: @jcalz The ```type``` alias can also work

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ANgEyQbwLACgkikBLYAFwgCcAzBZAMQHsmckQAuJKcqsgcyQBfANwFipCtTqIkAIRBU2AIy7AArmGXVhYwsTKVa9eSABebeF2Us0EEMF3ji5AJ4xGcuUgC8SZqwAPqZKwQpmes5E8EzAPEg0XAG+bJxIAETpwgRCBASgkLAmAHIQAO44UZJGMsgAkpX6EkQBXNjsXDx8wIJCADRVEgpUbUiqSBpaOv2DxOGjVmO29o65Tdnrbh7+Xil1ANoA1hCuTDRIdQC6kesA9Ldj6uR9kjz2WGdIZXzkAv4sSFO6gmTAqAAsQAA3ZDkVjfEiUC77dIBdKXF7KOzweBgqoxOLkBJcA4olholLtNKZDZVe5IJhKIFfEhoNBjZA0BmILCwpBUCAYCDwNCKGFgiBgF6Cmj2X49JDkcVIGDqKgwJhQCAcKpbRgAvwk1HXHJ5fCmoA) maybe? I think redundancy is probably inevitable.

Comment: @jcalz That's an interesting idea, thanks! Yeah unfortunately my gut feeling was that there is no nice way around it

Comment: If these interfaces are related, it might make sense for them to extend some base interface, so then you can use the type of your base interface which will include all extenders